# How to create hidden menu elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

The menu should pop up when mouse hover. As for comments on this site.

Comment: As comments do? Or as tags do?

Comment: Free I think you need to elaborate more on exactly what you want

Comment: As arrow and a flag at left side of this comment.

Comment: The CSS display property is what shows/hides it, but what you're looking for is a way to show a menu onMouseOver (I believe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick example would look something like this:

**HTML**

```
<p>Hover me for more text...<span>see, I told you!</span></p>
```

**CSS**

```
p span { display:none; }
p:hover span { display:inline; }
```

**Demo: [jsfiddle.net/fWK2e](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/fWK2e/)**

Expand on that concept and you can hide an element until it's parent is hovered, revealing more content such as links or images, etc. Just know that the `:hover` pseudo-class doesn't work on older browsers so you'll have to resolve that with JS.

Answer (score 1):

Or the JavaScript equivalent:

```
<p>Hover me for more text...<span style="display:none" onmouseover="this.style.display='inline'" onmouseout="this.style.display='none'">see, I told you!</span></p>
```